Install file doesnt work when installing ffmpeg
How to install ffmpeg on pc? It seems really complicated. I downloaded and extracted the files and then clicked on install.md but nothing.. Checked few places but couldn't understand the procedure. Do we need to write some code somewhere to be able to install this?

What operating system? Please [edit] the tags.

For Windows, the answer by Ricardo Bohner explains how to download
and install FFMPEG.
The page
Windows builds from gyan.dev
details alternative installation methods:

release essentials:
choco install ffmpeg
winget install "FFmpeg (Essentials Build)"

release full:
choco install ffmpeg-full
scoop install ffmpeg
winget install ffmpeg

release full shared:
scoop install ffmpeg-shared
winget install "FFmpeg (Shared)"

git master:
scoop install ffmpeg-gyan-nightly



For Windows:

Download FFmpeg
Extract the files where you want to store them, something like C:\Program Files\FFMPEG
Next press WINDOWS+R to open the run command
Type: sysdm.cpl and press ENTER.
Click the Advanced tab, Environment Variables
Add the path to ffmpeg.exe (only the path not including the filename) to the PATH variable in "user variables" something like:
C:\Program Files\FFMPEG\bin.

For more information with screenshots see
Installing FFmpeg on Windows.

If you are using Windows 11 the easiest way will be use the winget

open a terminal window
type winget install ffmpeg enter

then you should be good to go.
testing by run ffmepg at the terminal, you should see some output with version info etc.
